# Multiple views in same view controller?

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently, I have a storyboard with a view controller and a table view.

I want to add two other layouts to scene, both of them above the table view. But when I try to add a `UIView` above the table view (in the interface builder), it doesn't let me.

So my question is, how do I add multiple layouts to the same view controller?

Comment: Is there no way to simply add the views above the table view in the interface builder storyboard?

Comment: Is you current view controller a subclass of `UIViewController` or `UITableViewController`?  If it is the latter, then no, there is no easy way.

Comment: What happens if you start over and add the UIViews first and then the tableview below them?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Change the class of the view controller from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`. Then add two `UIView`s above a `UITableView`. This strategy will require you to wire up the dataSource, delegate and other features that `UITableViewController` provides.
2. Place the two `UIView`s in a header for the `UITableView` of the `UITableViewController`. This is what I recommend.